# Add Notes and attachments to lightning record page on lead object

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I would like to add notes and attachments component to a new lead record page but i am not able to find notes and attachments component from lightning app builder . i added notes and attachments as related list to page layout but i am unable to find in drag and drop components?

Answer (score 1):

i am able find the answer added the related list and select notes and attachments